# Adding class to react div onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to create a card component. I want to flip the card onClick. How to add the animation to rotate the card onClick? My code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FlipCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: true 
    }
  }   

cardClick=()=>{
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({
        active: !currentState
    });
}

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div 
                 className={this.state.active ? 'newCard, flipMe' : 'newCard'}
                 onClick = {this.cardClick}
                >
                    <div className='frontCard'> I'm Front </div>

                    <div className='backCard'> I'm Back </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            )
    }
}

export default FlipCard;
```

Styles:

```
.newCard{
  position: absolute;
  width:200px; height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 
}


.flipMe{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.frontCard{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%; height: 100%; background-color:grey;
  backface-visibility: hidden
}

.backCard{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%; height: 100%; background-color:grey;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
```

So when the card is clicked, I'm changing the state of active and I want the card to rotate and show the `backCard` div. If I add the `hover`, it works:

```
.newCard:hover{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

But I want it onClick and not hover. How do I do this?

Comment: When your app first renders, no card is displayed, only the "I'm Front" text in backwards position. Is this expected?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo No. This is not expected. I want the "I'm Front" text properly displayed and onClick want to flip the card and show the `backCard` div.

Comment: I think the `flipMe` styles do not get applied because of the comma `,` in `'newCard, flipMe'` `className` property. You should remove it `className={this.state.active ? 'newCard flipMe' : 'newCard'}`

Comment: @Somename does that fix the transition onClick as well?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Yes. It fixed the onClick transtion too.

Comment: @Somename that's so interesting. For whatever reason I don't see any effect taking place when I put your code in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-moon-bos8s. Is there something I'm not seeing :o

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Remove the `newCard12:hover` class and `.newCard12 { transform: rotateY(180deg); }`. It works!

Answer (score 2):

Give your element a ref attribute and change its classname with "this.refs" [like this](https://codepen.io/alibalouchi/pen/QWLqbyM):

```
class FlipCard extends React.Component {

handleClick(){
  this.refs.Card.classList.toggle("backCard");
  this.refs.Card.classList.toggle("frontCard");
  this.refs.frontCard.classList.toggle("deactive");
  this.refs.frontCard.classList.toggle("active");
  this.refs.backCard.classList.toggle("deactive");
  this.refs.backCard.classList.toggle("active");
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <div 
        ref="Card" 
        className="frontCard"
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
        <div 
          ref="frontCard" 
          className="active">Front Card</div>
        <div 
          ref="backCard" 
          className="back deactive">Back Card</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
}


export default FlipCard
```

CSS:

```
.frontCard{
  display: flex;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.backCard{
  transform: rotatey(180deg);
  transition: 1s ease;
  display: flex;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.deactive{
  display: none;
}
.back {
  transform: rotatey(180deg);
}

.active {
  display: block;
  transform: rotatey();
}
```